# ERROR "class ... does not have a main method

Tags: java, netbeans, poo

Tengo un pequeño problema con este error... al momento de arrojar me indica que no tengo un metodo... el cuál si tengo, la verdad es que no encuentro el error, necesito de su ayuda les dejo el codigo por si me pueden ayudar

```
package sistemalaboratorio;

import claseConectar.conectar;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author ESTACION 4
 */
public class Login extends javax.swing.JPanel {


        void acceder(String usuario, String pass)
    {
        String cap="";
       String sql="SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nick='"+usuario+"' && password='"+pass+"'";
        try {
            Statement st = cn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next())
            {
                cap=rs.getString("tipousuario");
            }
            if(cap.equals("Administrador"))
            {
                  this.setVisible(false);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido");
            //         ventanaadmin ingreso = new ventanaadmin();
            //        ingreso.setVisible(true);
            //        ingreso.pack();
            //         ventanaadmin.lblusu.setText(usuario);


            }
            if(cap.equals("Invitado"))
            {
            this.setVisible(false);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bienvenido");
             //        ventanacliente ingresos = new ventanacliente();
              //      ingresos.setVisible(true);
             //       ingresos.pack();
             //        ventanacliente.lblconectado.setText(usuario);
            }
            if((!cap.equals("Administrador"))&& (!cap.equals("Invitado")))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No existe sus datos");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        }
    /**
     * Creates new form Login
     */
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        lblPassword = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btningresar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        txtPassword = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        txtusuario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(238, 232, 232));
        jPanel2.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("USUARIO");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("CONTRASEÑA");

        lblPassword.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 255));
        lblPassword.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 255));
        lblPassword.setText("Recordar Contraseña");

        btningresar.setText("INGRESAR");
        btningresar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btningresarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(251, 251, 251)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 112, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(531, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(lblPassword, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 200, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btningresar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(59, 59, 59))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(207, 207, 207)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(57, 57, 57)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 57, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btningresar)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(lblPassword)
                .addGap(49, 49, 49))
        );

        txtPassword.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtPasswordActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel1.setText("DataLab (LIMS) Software Login");
        jLabel1.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(216, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 397, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(197, 197, 197))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 900, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(480, 480, 480)
                            .addComponent(txtPassword, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 158, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(480, 480, 480)
                            .addComponent(txtusuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 158, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 490, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(290, 290, 290)
                            .addComponent(txtPassword, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(210, 210, 210)
                            .addComponent(txtusuario, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(70, 70, 70)
                            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void txtPasswordActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void btningresarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

                String usu=txtusuario.getText();
    String pas=new String(txtPassword.getPassword());
    acceder(usu, pas);// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btningresar;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblPassword;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField txtPassword;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtusuario;
    // End of variables declaration                   
conectar cc= new conectar();
Connection cn= cc.conexion();
}
```

Comment: Por lo menos esta.. no tiene un metodo main.. o yo no lo veo..

Comment: Hola, el problema es que necesitas tener una clase `main` dentro de tu _package_ para hacer _run_, de otro modo no va a correr.

Comment: en _netbeans_ cuando creas un nuevo proyecto se crea automáticamente su clase _main_, puede que la hayas borrado accidentalmente, en todo caso puedes generarla otra vez, puedes crear una nueva clase y darle opción de clase main o puedes crear una clase con cualquier nombre, solo hace falta que tenga `public static void Clase(String[] args){` y dentro coloca el código que quieres que corra.

Comment: gracias @the-breaker ahora lo coloque pero no me muestra el Jframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error indica que en tu paquete o en tu clase no hay definido un método `main()`. No lo veo y para solucionarlo sugiero que lo incluyas.

Toda aplicación hecha en `Java` necesita un método `main()` dentro de la clase que se inicia para ejecutarse el programa. Este método es el que se ejecuta cuando una aplicación de `Java` es ejecutada, por lo tanto allí debes definir lo que tu programa en `Java` hará hasta terminarse.

El método `main()` debe estar contenido en la clase iniciadora que  debe llamar  igual que el fichero fuente en el que está declarado. Esta es la estructura para la declaración de un método `main()`:

```
public class NombreFichero
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
       // Aquí incluyes las instrucciones que tu programa ejecutará.
    }
}
```

Reemplazas `NombreFichero` por el nombre del fichero que contendrá la clase inicializadora que contendrá tu método `main()`.

En tu caso debes incluir el método `main()` en tu clase `Login`.

Answer (score 0):

En java el punto de inicio es el Main, desde alli es donde compilara rodo tu codigo. El metodo Main es:

```
public static void Clase(String[] args){
   //Aqui es donde se coloca el codigo que iniciara tu sistema.
}
```

Suerte...

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola:

Tube el mismo problema en InteliJ IDEA, en este caso tienes q seleccionar en el panel derecho superior, en qué clase se hará la ejecución... adjunto foto

Comment: Hola, esto no funcionaría si no antes se realizan modificaciones a la clase.