# class does not have a main method

Tags: java

[image: class does not have a main method]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) me muestra este error y no sé cómo solucionarlo.

Comment: Edwin, edita tu pregunta y reemplaza las imágenes por texto ya que es más legible de esa forma.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Todo programa en Java debe de tener un método main para poder ejecutarse, y tu programa no contiene ninguna clase que contenga dicho método.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [ERROR "class ... does not have a main method](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/162240/error-class-does-not-have-a-main-method)

Answer (score 0):

**Tu proyecto carece de una clase que contenga el método `main()` en el cual se inicia la ejecución del programa.**

Ejemplo:

```
package com.myapp;

import java.util.*;

public class Ejemplo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       //Inicialización

    }
}
```

Al agregar la clase `CONBASEDATOS` la IDE te indica que no tienes un método principal main() definido ("does not have a main method")

Te sugiero revisar este excelente articulo:

**[Cómo funciona el método main() en Java](https://javautodidacta.es/metodo-main-en-java/)**